# A react custom modal always open with the same content

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-component, react-modal

I've created a custom model to edit a TODO in a table and send a PUT request to the backend, each row has the description, edit and delete button.

The problem is when I click on the edit button the only content that appears in the modal is the last one on the table.

**This is my modal**

```
const EditTodo = ({todo, show, onClose, todo_id}) => {
    console.log(todo_id);
    if (!show) {
        return null;
    }

    const [description, setDescription] = useState(todo.description);
    return (      
       <Fragment>
           <div className="container-modal" onClick={onClose} id={`id${todo.todo_id}`}>
               <div className="content-modal" onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()} >           
                    <div className="header-modal">
                        <p>Edit Tasks</p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="body-modal">
                        <input className="input-modal" type="text" value={description} onChange={e => setDescription(e.target.value)} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="footer-modal">
                        <button>Save</button>    
                        <button onClick={onClose}>Close</button>    
                    </div>
                </div>
           </div>
           
       </Fragment>
     );
}
```

**The table with a button to open the modal**

```
const ListTodo = () => {

    const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
    const [description, setDescription] = useState([]);
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);


    // Delete function
    const deleteTodo = async (id) => {
        try {
            await fetch(URL+`${id}`, {
                method: "DELETE"
            });
            setTodos(todos.filter(todo => todo.id !== id));
            window.location = "/";
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }

    }



    const fetchTodos = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch(URL);
            const data = await response.json();
            setTodos(data);
            
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchTodos();
    },[])
    return (
    <table className="todo-table styled-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
               {todos.map(todo => (
                   <tr key={todo.todo_id}>
                        <td>{todo.description}                        
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <button data-target={`#id${todo.todo_id}`} onClick={() => setShow(true)}>Edit</button> 
                            <EditTodo onClose={() => setShow(false)} show={show} todo={todo} todo_id={`#id${todo.todo_id}`}/>
                            </td>
                        <td><button className="delete-btn" onClick={() => deleteTodo(todo.todo_id)}>Delete</button></td>
                   </tr>
               ))}        
        </tbody>
    </table>
    );
}
```

I'm new to react and it seems to be something basic but I'll appreciate your help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing Props (img url ) using React-Modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70707356/passing-props-img-url-using-react-modal)

Comment: It looks like you are creating and `<EditTodo>` modal for each to-do, but using the same `show` value for all of them. Ordinarily, one would create a single modal component (below your `</table>`, say), and change the modal's prop values to the correct to-do at the same time as setting `show={true}`.